# LiteDB throws unhandled exception when trying to open a shared connection

Tags: .net, nosql, mutex, litedb

I am developing on .net Framework 4.8 with LiteDb 5.0.17.0.

When I try to instantiate a database connection with:

```cs
Connection = new LiteDatabase("Filename=C:\\temp\\data.ldb;Connection=Shared");
```

I get the following error:

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'Void System.Threading.Mutex..ctor(Boolean, System.String, Boolean ByRef, System.Security.AccessControl.MutexSecurity)'.
  Source=LiteDB
  StackTrace:
   at LiteDB.SharedEngine..ctor(EngineSettings settings)
   at LiteDB.ConnectionString.CreateEngine()
   at LiteDB.LiteDatabase..ctor(ConnectionString connectionString, BsonMapper mapper)
```

It works fine if I omit the connection specification. The support/documentation for LiteDb is really poor, but managed to find a few odds and ends through google, but couldn't match to my particular use case. However, it looks like something to do with .net versions and Mutex (which I'm not familiar with).

It does say this in the documentation:

"The Shared mode only works in .NET implementations that provide named mutexes. Its multi-process capabilities will only work in platforms that implement named mutexes as system-wide mutexes."

However, I have no idea what this means, whether this applies to Framework 4.8 or not and indeed what to do as a result.

Any suggestions? It just feels like LiteDb is getting more and more difficult to work with, so hope there's some workaround as would like to continue to support it.

14.01.24: EDIT

I have established this is a specific issue when running as part of a plugin for an app. I have narrowed the issue down to a specific method in LiteDb, but cannot explore the error any further. The LiteDb code that leads to an exception, I believ, is this:

```cs
internal ILiteEngine CreateEngine()
{
    EngineSettings settings = new EngineSettings
    {
        Filename = Filename,
        Password = Password,
        InitialSize = InitialSize,
        ReadOnly = ReadOnly,
        Collation = Collation
    };
    ...(Removed for clarity)
    if (Connection == ConnectionType.Shared)
    {
        return new SharedEngine(settings); // Error is thrown by this call
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

For some reason, I can't step into `SharedEngine(settings)` to try and drill down further...

Comment: _" It just feels like LiteDb is getting more and more difficult to work with"_ - what makes you think that? I've always found it _extremely_ easy to use. Hardly ever need to go see docs. Now while it attempts to support shared access, I'd guess it's _not really intended for it_ which leads to sub-par experience. So, my question would be: what's your use case and does LiteDB fit the resulting requirements reasonably well?

Comment: _"However, I have no idea what this means"_ - what exactly? What a Mutex is? Or what a "named system-wide mutex" is in particular? Most OS provide means of ensuring mutual exclusivity ( mut ex => mutex ). Some languages/frameworks are implemented so that they use those, others have "less heavy" own techniques but of course with draw-backs (work only in-process, things like that). So, for LietDB, shared access only works if the file is protected by the OS through such a heavy OS Mutex.

Comment: Helpful primer on mutex, thanks. On your other point, given litedb has a shared connection designed into it, I think that it's rather a moot point? Getting hard to work with is really about the lack of support which us mere mortals need sometimes. I'm happy you have no problems. My use case requires shared access, all you need to know (it's always easy to rtfm, no?). Given your expertise, any ideas around how to get a shared connection working?

Comment: Unfortunately, haven't even tried that before. I personally would probably steer away from LiteDB for that kind of requirement. But if you can pin down the _exact_ runtime environment version this happens on, I am sure you'll get support from the guys themselves ... for example here: https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues

Comment: Oh yes. Have posted the full bug, but the dev never responds to posts and I think it's user base is shrinking due to poor support. Shame really. It's quite good. Another one bites the dust

Comment: Sad to hear that. Love that piece of software (using it for single-file, single-process, only though).

Comment: Can you link to the issue you posted on github?

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/2393

Comment: I am donating 50 of my rep to get this an exhausting an satisfying answer. I hope it helps. I really fell in love with this DB and I would hate it to vanish for lack of support. So, here is mine.

Comment: Is there a fully reproducing project? or can you details the exact step to reproduce? I've just tested with a .NET Fx 4.8 project + LiteDB nuget  5.0.17.0+ your simple code and it works. Note: MissingMethodException is generally a deployment issue (ie: some code expects some external dependency dll in a specific version). Maybe you're not really running with .NET Fx 4.8 for some reason (machine setup, app.config, etc.) but a lower version

Comment: Thanks @Fildor - I agree - I love LiteDb. Just the poor support/user base that's the issue.

Comment: Hmmm..  good + bad news . You're right, @SimonMourier, it does work fine as a stand alone solution. I even replicated the proj/lib structure and it worked OK. However, the 'live' code is a plugin for another application + when I run it in that domain/environment, I get the mutex error on Shared connection, but it works fine on Direct. So the error is somewhere between the two. Even tried moving the db file out of the parent application's directory. No dice. Urgh. When will I ever learn not to develop plugins? Thanks + sorry to Fildor for your support - at least we know the Shared works!

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you'll get it to work alltogether.

Comment: @stigzler - like I said it's probably a dependency/deployment issue with .NET and .NET dll used overall in that process, it's not directly related to LiteDb itself or database path, etc.

Comment: I think you might be right. The parent app is WPF heavy and I think routing around the stack trace, WPF came up somewhere and my plugin doesn't use WPF - so must be the influence of the parent app I'm thinking. Damn - this is going to introduce a real headache :/

Comment: You can check what's loaded or what's not or what's unexpected using tools such as fuslogvw to check .NET loading & errors (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) procexp to check dll (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) procmon (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)